# Best practices to minimize duplicate css with compass for rtl and ltr

Tags: css, compass-sass, right-to-left, susy-compass

Is there any way that compass/sass can assist in minimizing the amount of duplicate css code when making your layout work both for rtl and ltr languages?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that [Bi-App-Sass](http://anasnakawa.github.com/bi-app-sass/) does exactly what I was looking for:

> usually when writing stylesheets for bi-directional sites/apps, both ltr & rtl stylesheets mostly will look the same, except for direction related properties (float, text-align, padding, margin ..etc ), so when you write a float: left in some ltr stylesheet, you'll have to write it again as float: right for the rtl one
>
> when using bi-app-sass , all you have to do is to write your stylesheets once using a predefined mixins for those direction related properties, and once you compile your stylesheets, you'll have a ready two stylesheets for your bi-directional app

Answer (score 1):

You could write a mixin utilizing the @content blocks feature of Sass 3.2.

Like so:

```
@mixin rtl {
    [dir="rtl"] & {
        @content;
    }
}

.module {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2em;    

    // Change directions and reverse the margin
    @include rtl {
        float: right;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 2em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could use something like `$from-direction: right;` and `float: $from-direction` and the compass helper `float: opposite-position($from-direction)`

Comment: Welll, that does not really de-duplicate content within compass. The outputted css will always be duplicate, but I was looking for a way to solve that within SASS/Compass. Have found a solution, which I will add as an answer